# Discord Bot that Plays an Audio File When Someone Joins

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like the bot to join a voice channel when someone joins and then play a sound file.

So far, I've gotten the bot to join the voice channel but it just doesn't play the sound and no errors show so I don't really know what is going wrong.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.login('BOT TOKEN');

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel
  let textChannel = oldMember.guild.channels.get('TEXTCHANNEL ID')

  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

    if (newMember.id === 'MEMEBER ID')         //Member 1
    {   
       newUserChannel.join()
       .then(connection => {
          console.log("Joined voice channel!");
          const dispatcher = connection.playFile("C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Welcome_Bot\music\bossman.mp3");

          dispatcher.on("end", end => {newUserChannel.leave()});
       })
        .catch(console.error);

    }
      else if (newMember.id === 'MEMEBER ID')       //Member 2
      {
       textChannel.send('Hello Member 2')
      }
        else if (newMember.id === 'MEMEBER ID')      //Member 3
        {
          textChannel.send('Hello Member 3')
        }
           else                                      //Random
           {
             textChannel.send("Hello") 
           } 
  } 
});
```

Comment: I am suspecting about the link to your sound audio. Should it be something like "http://....*.mp3" instead? otherwise the web will not understand your localpath

Comment: @ducmai To play a local file, the current setup is fine. The [Discord.js docs example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=playFile) uses an absolute path like the code above.

Comment: Is your username actually `NAME`? That's what's in your path. If not, that would be why nothing is played.

Comment: @slothiful I just put place holders into the question

Comment: @SeanCarson Do you have metadata tags within the mp3 file? Like artist, album, etc.?

Comment: @ slothiful I don't. I've also used other files so I don't think the problem will be with the file itself.

Comment: Could you try a relative path, and do `dispatcher.on("debug", console.log)`

Comment: @PLASMAchicken no luck there either and I'm getting nothing from the console.

Comment: You could update to d.js v12(master), that has a full voice rewrite but al sso brings breaking changes, `npm i discordjs/discord.js` to get v12

Comment: Have you tried to use await-async instead of `then` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that the bot isn't actually joining the channel before you call the dispatcher. The bot needs to be told to enter the channel before you call the dispatcher. Havn't worked on audio in a while but I believe that `connection.join()` right above your dispatcher would work. You may need to `.then()` to ensure it dosn't initilize the dispatcher before the bot joins the channel.